# erlang:monotonic_time badarg - is the doc incorrect?

Tags: erlang

When using `monontonic_time/1`, my shell only accepts unit `seconds` and not `second` (as per [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#type-time_unit)):

```
2> erlang:monotonic_time(seconds).
9

5> erlang:monotonic_time(second).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:monotonic_time/1
        called as erlang:monotonic_time(second)
```

Anyone else have this weird issue?
I'm running Erlang 19.

Comment: Are you on 19.0? These were added in 19.1: https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/412b5aaa5810cbac75ef41d29a36898ff1480129

Comment: @A.Sarid which is why `seconds` (the one deprecated in 19.1) works in both 19.0 and 19.1 while `second` (the new one) only works in 19.1.. or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Dogbert Yeah, I am on 19.0! Oh thanks, thought they were added in 19.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably on Erlang 19.0. The singular + non-underscored versions were added in [this commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/412b5aaa5810cbac75ef41d29a36898ff1480129) and according to Github, the first tag to include this commit was [`OTP-19.1`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases/tag/OTP-19.1) or Erlang/OTP version 19.1. I can confirm both `second` and `seconds` work for me in Erlang 19.1:

```
$ erl -eval '{ok, Version} = file:read_file(filename:join([code:root_dir(), "releases", erlang:system_info(otp_release), "OTP_VERSION"])), io:fwrite(Version), halt().' -noshell
19.1
```

```
$ erl
1> erlang:monotonic_time(second).
-576460744
2> erlang:monotonic_time(seconds).
-576460743
```